# What weapons have a flashlight?

Tags: killing-floor

The flashlight integrated into the default 9mm pistol is eminently useful, but sometimes you need something with a little extra oomph. Are there any other weapons that have a flashlight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the [9mm pistol](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/9mm_tactical_pistol), [shotgun](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Shotgun), [combat shotgun](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Combat_shotgun) and [Vlad the Impaler](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Vlad_the_Impaler) all have flashlights.